# Convert line uri to UK friendly format

Tags: regex, powershell

I have downloaded a script from Microsoft which will allow us to take a string and convert it into a friendly format to display on user profiles.

The original string is `tel:+441234123456;ext=3456`.

What I need to do is convert it into a UK friendly format so that the converted string is `01234 123456`.

The steps I think I need to take are :

- Removing the `tel:+44` and replacing with 0.
- After first 4 digits add a space.
- Finish the variable with the last 6 digits.
- Remove the `;ext=3456`

There was a similar process but for  US suggested, unfortunately no knowing regex this goes over my head slightly!

```
$tel = $LineURI -replace 'tel:(\+1)([2-9]\d{2})([2-9]\d{2})(\d{4});ext=\d{4}','$1 ($2) $3-$4;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a way using more than one `-replace` To simplify things at the cost of some performance:

```
$tel = $LineURI-replace 'tel:\+\d\d','0' -replace ';.+' -replace '(^.{5})','$1 '
```

Answer (score 1):

A single regular expression should suffice:

```
PS C:\> 'tel:+441234123456;ext=3456' -replace '^tel:\+\d{2}(\d{4})(\d+);.*$', '0$1 $2'
01234 123456
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^tel:\+\d{2}` matches a literal `tel:+` followed by two digits at the beginning of the string (`^`).
- `(\d{4})` matches four subsequent digits. The parentheses group the match so that it can be referenced in the replacement as `$1`.
- `(\d+)` matches the longest sequence of subsequent digits after the above, but at least one digit. This too is grouped by parentheses so that it can be referenced in the replacement as `$2`.
- `;.*$` matches the remainder of the string starting with a semicolon.